# Google map building style

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to style the building in google map, like openlayer did?
http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/vector/style.html

I've been style google map with other elements, not label, only show roads and buildings, all i need to do is enhance the color of the buildings.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ["Styled Maps"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) and style "Landscape -> Man Made"

[Discussion in the Google Maps API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/1d560dac6ff6b4bb)