# Google Maps Javascript API fill color of buildings

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am aware my question is very similar to [Google map building style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127409/google-map-building-style)

However, the solution provided there doesn't seem to achieve my goal.

I am trying to use a custom map style to change the fill color of buildings. When I set `landscape.man_made` with `geometry.fill` it sets that color for the landscape of all urban areas and when I set `geometry.stroke` it sets that color for building outlines.

My question is can I specifically set the fill color for buildings only and if so can you provide a simple code sample of what the JSON would look like?

**EDIT**

It seems as though this may not be possible by default. Does anyone know if there is a way then to retrieve the geometry of a featureType? I will be doing my own looking but my idea is if that data can be gotten, then custom shapes could be drawn on the map corresponding to the outlines (`landscape.man_made` -> `geometry.stroke`) with the desired fill color. If I find anything I will update here, but it anyone already knows how to retrieve the information it would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After researching further I have determined it's curently not possible to achieve my desired result with the Google Maps API.

It does seem that it's possible to retrieve individual map tiles and process them such that it replaces the default building color with a more unique one, then use that image to find building borders and their corner coordinates to dray a polygon over the map. However, this seems an extraneous amount of work and processing for such a result, especially if you want to do it to all the building on the screen as I do.

Comment: Tx for the answer after rying to have this. Any update on that topic? How do we can colorize buildings dynamically, for example on age basis etc?

Comment: I never found a way to do it. The project was dropped about a year ago and even while I was still working on it, this was of low importance since it appeared to not be possible so not much was done with the colorization after I submitted the answer.

Comment: this does not make sense right? if i apply geometry.stroke, the buildings are marked properly with the color i am providing but when we set fill, it does not fill just the square area with the color given. it fills the blank spaces between the builds as well with that same color which is weird. solution to this problem even now in 2021 is not made. would love to colorise the buildings of specific things with different color.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE 2022!

[image: 1]

It is possible by:

```js
{
  featureType: "landscape.man_made.building",
  elementType: "geometry.fill",
  stylers: [ 
    { color: "#ffff00"} ]
}
```

Comment: It`s Working! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Google maps JSON style guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference) for your exact needs.

Maybe

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
zoom: 12,
styles: [
   {
     featureType: 'poi',
     stylers: [
       { "color": "#99FF33" }
     ]
   }, {
    featureType: "landscape.man_made ",
    stylers: [
       { "color": "#99FF33" }
     ]
   }
 ]
});
```

Comment: I tried this, however it still only results in the sub-categories of poi being colored. I'm trying to get all buildings including residential. In a default Google Map they are outlined (landscape.mane_made -> geometry.stroke)to show that they are there but I can't find a control to fill them with a color.

Comment: IDK how to solve this. Check out the JSON guide for all of the options available to you. If you figure it out, update us!

Comment: I've dug around the style guide and tried nearly every featureType to no success. I've also toyed with https://snazzymaps.com/editor as it seems to be fairly comprehensive but the closest I've gotten is the same result described in the OP.

Comment: I have an idea I will look into, see my EDIT section of the OP. I will update if I find a solution.